# Jquery Parsing json response in ajax success fn

Tags: jquery, json

I have an ajax fn. My data variable gives me this response

```
[{"id":1,"name":"x"},{"id":2,"name":"y"},{"id":3,"name":"z"}]
```

How do I get id,name. I tried using

```
JSON.Parse(data[i])
    for(var i=0; i <data.length; i++){
      console.log(data[i].id);
    }
```

My console says unexpected end of data.

Comment: first of all the method is JSON.parse
second, make sure you get the proper response - is your data _the string_ or is it actually already _parsed object_ (which is default for jquery if server responds with the proper content-type)?

Comment: @Guard:In this link http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/extensions/array.html. I am using all_to_array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this.it may help

```
data=$.parseJSON(data)
$.each(data,function(i,e){
    alert(e.id);
});
```

Comment: :TypeError: $.ParseJSON is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

data=$.ParseJSON(data)

Comment: @user2261231 try with lowercase `p`

Comment: @JanDvorak:It is alreting.I do not want to alert.What is e here ?

Comment: @user2261231 the alert is just to demonstrate how to access the ID. `e` is the array element whose ID you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    for(var i=0; i <data.length; i++){
      alert(data[i].id);
      alert(data[i].name);
    }
```

Comment: that is incorrect `JSON.Parse(data[i])` it should be `JSON.Parse(data)`

Comment: @MohammadAdil actually, it should be `JSON.parse(data)`